# Initializing an array of a certain type using another array (C#)

Tags: c#

This is my question:
Let's say I have a class with such a constructor:

```
Class A {
   private int i;
   public A(int new_i) {
      i = new_i;
   }
}
```

Can I initialize an array of A with an array of int?
If so, how can I do it?
I was thinking something like:

```
int[] b = new int[5] { 0,1,2,3,4}; 
A[] a; 
a = new A[](b);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
var a = Array.ConvertAll(b, item => new A(item));
```

The advantage here is that it will be created with the right size, without any intermediate steps - plus it works without LINQ.

In C# 2.0 it is a bit uglier - the following is ***identical***:

```
A[] a = Array.ConvertAll<int,A>(b,
    delegate(int item) { return new A(item); });
```

The combination of `var`, lambdas, and improved generic type inference really shine for C# 3.0 here.

Comment: +1 for ConvertAll. BTW, the complexity of the 2nd version IMHO suggest to use an old-good for loop in C# 2.0 (it's just a couple of lines of code...)

Answer (score 3):

You could use LINQ:

```
int[] b = new int[5] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }; 
A[] a = b.Select(x => new A(x)).ToArray();
```